# Como gerar valor ao clicar em um input type submit

Tags: php, javascript, html

Formulário para enviar os dados selecionados para exclusão.

```
<form action="index.php?pagina=../controller/controllerUser&acao=ok" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">           
                        <label>Nome:</label>
                        <input class="input-xlarge" type="text" value="<?php echo $nome; ?>" name="nome" autofocus=""> <br/>

                        <label>CPF:</label>
                        <input class="input-large" type="text" name="cpf"  autofocus=""> <br/>

                        <label>Senha:</label>
                        <input class="input-large" type="text" name="senha"  autofocus=""> <br/>

                        <label>Repetir a senha:</label>
                        <input class="input-large" type="text" name="confirmarSenha"  autofocus=""> <br/>

                        <label>CEP:</label>
                        <input class="input-medium" type="text" name="cep"  autofocus=""> <br/>

                        <label>Endereço</label>
                        <input class="input-xlarge" type="text" name="descricao"  autofocus=""> <br/>

                        <label>Complemento</label>
                        <input class="input-xlarge" type="text" name="complemento" autofocus=""> <br/>


                </div>
                <div class="span6">

                    <label>E-mail</label>
                        <input class="input-xlarge" type="text" name="email" autofocus=""> <br/>

                    <label>Telefone</label>
                    <input class="input-xlarge" type="text" name="telefone"  autofocus=""> <br/>

                    <label>Telefone Dois</label>
                    <input class="input-xlarge" type="text" name="telefoneDois"  autofocus=""> <br/>    

                    <label>Selecione um País</label>
                    <select required="" name="id_pais">
                        <?php
                        $daoPais->selecionaTodosPaises();
                        ?>
                    </select>


                    <label>Selecione um estado</label>    
                    <select required="" name="idEstado" id="idEstado" onchange="getValorEstado(this.value, 0)">
                        <option selected="" disabled="" value="nulo">Selecione o ESTADO</option>
                        <?php
                        $daoEstado->selecionaTodosEstados();
                        ?>
                    </select>

                    <label>Selecione uma Cidade</label>    
                    <select required="" id="idCidade" name="idCidade">
                        <option selected="" disabled="" value="nulo">Selecione o ESTADO ANTES</option>
                        <!-- chadamada de arquivo aqui com jquery utilizando
                             ajax, o arquivo se encontra uteis/selectCidade.php-->
                    </select>
                    <br></br>


                    <input class="btn btn-large btn-primary" type="submit" value="salvar">
                    <a class="btn btn-large btn-danger" href="index.php?pagina=PaginaResumo" value="Cancelar">Cancelar</a>
                    </form>
```

irá redirecionar para a pagina de controller que insere ou exclui até o momento.

```
if (isset($_GET["acao"]) and $_GET["acao"] == "ok") {

//primeiro inserir o endereço
//atributos de endereço
$descricao = $_POST["descricao"];
$complemento = $_POST["complemento"];
$cep = $_POST["cep"];
$idCidade = $_POST["idCidade"];


//objeto de endereco
$endereco = new EnderecoEntity("", $descricao, $complemento, $cep, $idCidade);

//dao de endereço
$daoEndereco = new EnderecoDao();
$idEndereco = $daoEndereco->inserirEndereco($endereco);

//depois inserir o usuário com id de endereço

$nome = $_POST["nome"];
$cpf = $_POST["cpf"];
$senha = $_POST["senha"];

$usuario = new UsuarioEntity("", $nome, $cpf, $senha, $idEndereco);

$usuarioDao = new UsuarioDao();
$idUsuario = $usuarioDao->inserirUsuario($usuario);


//depois inserir o telefone com id de usuário
$telefoneUm = $_POST["telefone"];
$telefoneDois = $_POST["telefoneDois"];

$telefone = new TelefoneEntity("", $telefoneUm, $telefoneDois, $idUsuario);
$telefoneDao = new TelefoneDao();
$telefoneDao->inserirTelefone($telefone);


//depois inserir email com id de usuário
$email = $_POST["email"];
$email = new EmailEntity("", $email, $idUsuario);
$emailDao = new EmailDao();
$emailDao->inserirEmail($email);
 }
if (isset($_GET["acao"]) and $_GET["acao"] == "deletar") {

$idEndereco = $_GET["id_endereco"];
$idPessoa = $_GET["id"];
//verificação de confirmação do usuário
?>   
<div class="alert alert-error">
    //o ponto de erro é esse sei que vou perder os dados quando tentar retornar para esse form
    <form action="index.php?pagina=../controller/controllerUser&acao=deletarConcluido"> method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <h4>Atenção!</h4>
        Você realmente deseja excluir o usuário: 
        <?php
        echo $_GET["nome"];
        echo'<br/>';
        echo ' <a class="btn btn-primary" href="index.php?pagina=PaginaResumo">Não</a>';
        echo ' <input type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" value="SIM">';
    ?>  
    </form>
</div>
<?php
 if(isset($_GET["acao"]) and $_GET["acao"] == "deletarConcluido") {

    $idEndereco = $_GET["id_endereco"];
    $idPessoa = $_GET["id"];

    //Deletar email
    $emailDao = new EmailDao();
    $emailDao->deleteEmail($idPessoa);

    //deletar telefone
    $telefoneDao = new TelefoneDao();
    $telefoneDao->deleteTelefone($idPessoa);

    //Deletar usuario
    $usuarioDao = new UsuarioDao();
    $usuarioDao->deletePessoa($idPessoa);

    //Deletar endereço
    $enderecoDao = new EnderecoDao();
    $enderecoDao->deleteEndereco($idEndereco);
} 
}
```

Comment: Coloca um hidden field no form.

Comment: o problema é que são dois forms diferentes, ou seja em um eu tenho uma tabela, e no outro apenas dois botões, se eu passar uma variavel nesse outro ele perde os valores anteriores, é a mistureba do php sem framework parece servelet.

Comment: Confesso que não entendi muito bem, mas porque perderia o valor se adicionar um hidden field? Estaria apenas acrescentado. Você pode executar apenas um form por vez, então se acrescentar o hidden no form que será executado, não vejo problema. Mas edite a pergunta e coloque esses forms pra eu poder entender melhor.

Comment: Creio que o problema seja a logica, e não o form. Descreva melhor o caso.

Comment: Fazer uma confirmação de exclusão para um trabalho mais adequado para javascript do php, poste o código dos dois forms.

Comment: o problema é que teria que submeter o outro formulário, acredito que se gerasse uma variável em javascript e passasse a mesma poderia dar certo

Comment: testei coloca no form do controller assim mas não deu certo <form action="index.php?pagina=../controller/controllerUser&acao=deletarConcluido&idEndereco='.<?php echo $idEndereco ?>.'&idPessoa='.<?php echo $idPessoa?>.'" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">

Comment: Só nao entendi porque você nao cria o botao deletar dentro deste formulario? Ai ao invez de você usar o get voce usa o post

Comment: @Andrei Coelho a funcionalidade do delete está ok, o que estou precisando é fazer uma confirmação neste form para realmente o usuário que quiser deletar fazer isso ou simplesmente desistir e não fazer isso.

Comment: Entendi. Acho que com javascript resolve. Coloquei a tag javascript nas tags para ver se aparece um profissional nesta linguagem

Comment: @rray acabei de postar o código, alguma sugestão?

Comment: Esse form é para criar um registro e excluir? ele será usado para fazer alterações tbm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Voce pode fazer dessa forma:

```
<div class="alert alert-error">
        <h4>Atenção!</h4>
        Você realmente deseja excluir o usuário: 
        <?php
        echo $_GET["nome"];
        echo'<br/>';
        ?>

        <a class="btn btn-primary" href="index.php?pagina=PaginaResumo">Não</a>
        <a class="btn btn-primary" href="index.php?pagina=../controller/controllerUser&acao=deletarConcluido&id_endereco=<?php echo $id_endereco; ?>&id=<?php echo $id_pessoa; ?>">Sim</a>


</div>
```

Poste o resultado e nós iremos melhorando se precisar.

Atualização:

Dessa forma você não precisa gerar aquele form em php, a página nem vai precisar ser recarregada para gerar a confirmação:

```
<script>
function confirmarDelete(delUrl) {
  if (confirm("Você realmente deseja excluir o usuário?")) {
    document.location = delUrl;
  }
}
</script>

<a href="javascript:confirmarDelete('index.php?pagina=../controller/controllerUser&acao=deletarConcluido&id_endereco=<?php echo $id_endereco; ?>&id=<?php echo $id_pessoa; ?>')">Deletar</a>
```

Lembrando que essa é uma forma básica de fazer, existem jeitos mais avançados e mais personalizados, mas isso já vai te dar uma boa base para iniciar.

Comment: sim já tinha tentado dessa forma, passa os parametros tranquilamente novamente, até tinha colocado em um comentário anterior, agora não sei por que ele não entra na verificação se existe a variável if(isset($_GET['acao'])) { faça algo.... mesmo mostrando a acao na url ele não está entrando nessa condição.

Answer (score 0):

@Diego Machado ocorreu tudo bem só coloquei no form as variáveis pois o sistema está quase todo dessa forma então ficou da seguinte forma:

```
<div class="alert alert-error">
    <form action="index.php?pagina=../controller/controllerUser&novaAcao=deletarConcluido&id_endereco=<?php echo $idEndereco; ?>&id=<?php echo $idPessoa;?>" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <h4>Atenção!</h4>
        Você realmente deseja excluir o usuário: 
        <?php
            echo $_GET["nome"];
            echo'<br/>';
            echo ' <a class="btn btn-primary" href="index.php?pagina=PaginaResumo">Não</a>';
            echo '<input type="submit" value="Sim" class="btn btn-primary" >';
        ?>        
    </form>
```

Dúvidas que ficaram:
1) essa é a forma mais correta de fazer?
2) essa forma está correta?

Comment: Vou ser sincero, não acho essa uma forma eficiente. Acaba complicando seu código. Provavelmente você deve ter uma lista com botões para deletar, que quando clicados levam para essa página, certo? Todos os dados deveriam estar no link, como mostrei. A confirmação deveria vir através de um javascript, veja esse exemplo simples: http://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_confirm
Dessa forma a página não precisa ser carregada, e você não precisa criar um formulário para confirmar. Você vai apenas redirecionar. Vou montar um exemplo depois para você.